# Calculate Sum of times

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, reporting-services, rdlc

Hi I'm creating an RDLC Report for an attendance management system. In my report I want to Sum of total `WorkedHours`.

I Want exactly this output

```
EmployeeId EmployeeName  WorkedHours
1             ABC        04:00:25
2             XYZ        07:23:01
3             PQR        11:02:15
```

SO i want to display total of all 3 employees at the end of report in RDLC.

like Total: 22:25:41

Comment: Please provide more information about your database schema and the data contained therein.

Comment: Please show your current sql.

Comment: What if the total is > 24 hours. Certainly, on the SQL side of things, there's only a `datetime` datatype, that expects to be working with times of day, not the duration of time spans.

Comment: No matter total is > 24..i just want total of that column..and WorkedHours field type Is VARCHAR.

Comment: I have tried this but its not worked.                                  =Sum(Format((Fields!TotalEmpWorkedHrs.Value / 86400),"hh:mm:ss"))

Comment: You changed your question to be *Calculate sum of times* and now answers about difference between two times, which was your previous question, make no sense. Why couldn't you just ask a *new* question?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select EmpId,In_duration,out_duration,
    datediff(mi,in_duration,out_duration) as Diff_mins
from table
```

the first parameter in DateDiff is mi (minutes).   If you look up dateDiff in documentation, you'll see the other options.   The example below shows difference in hours, minutes, and seconds as a string.

```
select   
 LTRIM(STR(DATEDIFF(mi,in_duration,out_duration) /60))+':'+
 LTRIM(STR(DATEDIFF(mi,in_duration,out_duration) %60))+':'+
 LTRIM(STR(DATEDIFF(ss,in_duration,out_duration) -   
          (DATEDIFF(ss,in_duration,out_duration)/60)*60))
as diff
```

Comment: I want diff in Hour:Min:sec and then sum of all Hour:Min:sec.

Comment: How can i sum of diff in RDLC Report ?

Comment: Select   
 LTRIM(STR(Sum(mi,EmployeeTempAttendanceDetail.TotalEmpWorkedHrs) /60))+':'+
LTRIM(STR(Sum(mi,EmployeeTempAttendanceDetail.TotalEmpWorkedHrs) %60))+':'+
LTRIM(STR(Sum(ss,EmployeeTempAttendanceDetail.TotalEmpWorkedHrs) -   
(Sum(ss,EmployeeTempAttendanceDetail.TotalEmpWorkedHrs)/60)*60)) 
As diff

Comment: i want to sum of this EmployeeTempAttendanceDetail.TotalEmpWorkedHrs  how can i achieve it ?

Comment: Not sure what you mean, a single row at the end of the report with the sum?  I would add a column to the report contain the difference in total seconds, then sum this row, and use the formatting above to convert the total of those seconds into a hh:mm:dd format

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @T table
(
  EmployeeId int,
  EmployeeName varchar(10),
  WorkedHours varchar(8)
)

insert into @T
select 1, 'ABC', '04:00:02' union all
select 2, 'XYZ', '07:23:01' union all
select 3, 'PQR', '11:02:15'

select right(100+T2.hh, 2)+':'+right(100+T2.mm, 2)+':'+right(100+T2.ss, 2) as TotalHours
from (
      select dateadd(second, sum(datediff(second, 0, cast(WorkedHours as datetime))), 0) as WorkedSum
      from @T 
     ) as T1
cross apply (select datediff(hour, 0, T1.WorkedSum) as hh, 
                    datepart(minute, T1.WorkedSum) as mm, 
                    datepart(second, T1.WorkedSum) as ss) as T2
```

1. Convert WorkedHours to datetime
2. Calculate the number of seconds since 1900-01-01T00:00:00
3. Sum the seconds for all rows
4. Convert seconds to datetime
5. Use `datediff` to calculate the number of hours
6. Use `datepart` to get minutes and seconds
7. Build the resulting string and use `right(100+T...)` to add `0` before value if neccesary.

The `cross apply ...` part is not necessary. I added that to make the code clearer. You can use the expressions in the `cross apply` directly in the field list if you like.

Comment: How can i do sum of totalworkedhour in RDLC report..?  totalworkedhour type is varchar..totalworkedhour is like 04:13:00..